# how to force to function execute only when after another async function complete

Tags: reactjs, react-native, async-await

I want to know if the length of meetings is bigger than 1 for showing to user if he can appointment another meeting (permitted max one meeting in a week) so I need it inside `useEffect`.

```
     state.userMeetings.length > 1 ? console.log("bigger") : console.log("less then 1");

    useEffect(() => {
        getUserMeetings(user.token, user.userId);////async function
        check();
    }, []);
```

now all the stuff behind doesnt matter:
i call getUserMeeting and get array of meetings :
**the problem**: when i first render/get inside the component i get **"less then 1"**(note that in userMeetings array there is more then one meet) in check function,

after the first render if i going back and for and its working as expected and return me **"bigger"**

**the question:** why in the first i'm get less than one, if I'm exec the getUserMeeting?
maybe is not to wait to finish the "getUserMeeting"?
how can I forces him to first finish the async function, and after exec the check() function?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchMyAPI() {
      let response = await getUserMeetings(user.token, user.userId); //async function
      check();
    }

    fetchMyAPI()
  }, [])
```

Comment: i get error:

Warning: An effect function must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.

It looks like you wrote useEffect(async () => ...) or returned a Promise. Instead, write the async function inside your effect and call it immediately:

useEffect(() => {
  async function fetchData() {
    // You can await here
    const response = await MyAPI.getData(someId);
    // ...
  }
  fetchData();
}, [someId]); // Or [] if effect doesn't need props or state